# Number of ways to calculate the sum of 3 objectives

Tags: java, recursion

For a given `num=4`, and the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, which their values can range from `1 to 10`. I want to count the number of ways that is possible to add those 3 variables to get the value `num`. For example, for `num=4`

```
1+1+2, 2+1+1, 1+2+1
```

there is 3 ways

I am trying to this using recursion. Maybe I am missing something big here, I would be with your advice!

```java
// we can assume the values are positive
// we can assume the num is geater than 4
public static int numbers(int a, int b, int c, int num) {
    Integer counter = 0;
    if (a + b + c > num) {
        return 0;
    }

    // if we reached a variation of num we add to counter
    if (a + b + c == num) {
        return counter++;
    }

    // if we didnt reach a variation of 0
    // we do recurion to a+1 then recurion where we add to b and c
    if (a + b + c < num && a < num - 1 && b < num - 1 && c < num - 1) {
        return numbers(a++, b, c, num) + numbers(a, b++, c, num);
    }

    // we add to c if its not equal to a so we dont get double
    if (a + b + c < num && a < c) {
        return numbers(a, b, c++, num);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Why not count 103?

Comment: Hi I have the correct solution for this problem if you still are interested

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with your method, namely :

```
  return counter++;
```

should actually be `return 1;`

You cannot increment the variables (e.g., `a++`) otherwise during the recursive calls you will not go through all the possible paths. Here:

```
return numbers(a++, b, c, num) + numbers(a, b++, c, num);
```

you only have two paths but there is actually 3, namely:

```
        return  numbers(a + 1, b, c, num) +
                numbers(a, b + 1, c, num) +
                numbers(a, b, c + 1, num);
```

However, the problem with the algorithm now is that it will have duplicated recursion paths. Hence, you adapt the method to avoid that situation:

```
public static void numbers(int a, int b, int c, int num, Set<String> combinations){
    if (a + b + c <= num) {
        if (a + b + c == num) {
            combinations.add("(" + a + "," + b + "," + c + ")");
        } else {
            numbers(a + 1, b, c, num, combinations);
            numbers(a, b + 1, c, num, combinations);
            numbers(a, b, c + 1, num, combinations);
        }
    }
}
```

using a set to avoid the duplication.

A running example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void numbers(int a, int b, int c, int num, Set<String> combinations){
        if (a + b + c <= num) {
            if (a + b + c == num) {
                combinations.add("(" + a + "," + b + "," + c + ")");
            } else {
                numbers(a + 1, b, c, num, combinations);
                numbers(a, b + 1, c, num, combinations);
                numbers(a, b, c + 1, num, combinations);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set<String> combinations =  new LinkedHashSet<>();
        numbers(1, 1, 1, 5, combinations);
        combinations.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("Count : "+combinations.size());
    }
}
```

For the input:

```
numbers(1, 1, 1, 5, combinations);
```

you would get the output:

```
(3,1,1)
(2,2,1)
(2,1,2)
(1,3,1)
(1,2,2)
(1,1,3)
Count : 6
```